# Where is the Immediate Scheduler in rxJava3?

Tags: java, rx-java, scheduler

In [rxJava 1](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/schedulers/Schedulers.html) there was `Scheduler.immediate()` which let you schedule work on the current thread. In [rxJava 3](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/schedulers/Schedulers.html) I can no longer find this scheduler.

Does anyone know what the replacement for `Scheduler.immediate()` is in rxJava 3?

---

**My use case**:

I have a client-side API which I use to subscribe to an infinite stream of events (e.g. a news feed) from a remote server. The API notifies me of events via a callback which I register:

```
Observable.create(emitter -> apiClient.registerCallback(event -> emitter.onNext(event)))
        .observeOn(Schedulers.immediate())   // I'd like downstream operators to run on current thread
        .map(myFunc);
```

However, the API calls my callback from a different thread. I wish to run downstream computations like `myFunc` on the current thread (the one that created the `Observable`) so as not to block the API's thread.

Comment: [It has been removed in 2.x](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#schedulers) because its use was quite limited and error prone. In addition, it has no practical effect with `Observable` in your example as `myFunc` will always run on the caller thread executing `emitter.onNext`. Also you may not be able to return to "the current thread" without it being already on a `Scheduler` or blocking.

Comment: @akarnokd thanks. However, I don't understand why this is true: "`myFunc` will always run on the caller thread executing `emitter.onNext`". Won't the call to `.observeOn(Schedulers.immediate())` change downstream operations to a different thread?

Comment: No. `Scheduler.immediate()` does not introduce any threads to the flow and thus an `observeOn` with it is a no-op.

Comment: @akarnokd i see -- then i guess my question is: how would I run `.map(myFunc)` on the thread that created the observable (via `Observable.create()`)?

Comment: What thread does your `create` run in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, in RxJava 3 you can employ [ImmediateThinScheduler](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/0668d042b47d3585f856af831bd3b1e1742c080f/src/main/java/io/reactivex/rxjava3/internal/schedulers/ImmediateThinScheduler.java) to obtain the same effect.
Although it's kept in the `internal` package, you can use it.

The API is so simple you can actually create one yourself if you don't want to depend on their `internal` package.